# Get phone number while in call

Tags: android, android-developer-api

is there a way to retrieve the phone number of the other party in an ongoing call?
I know that I would be able to get it that moment that call comes in or goes out using an broadcast receiver and `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` or `EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER`. But how do I get the number if the call is already ongoing?

Edit:
Currently I've this, but I want to be able to query the number of an call that is already active before my app is launched:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
        intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you register a `PhoneStateListener` for `LISTEN_CALL_STATE` you should get a `onCallStateChanged` with the current state and a phone number for ongoing calls (not sure if it works for outgoing calls, or only for ingoing calls). Why can't you put your `BroadcastReceiver` in a service though?

Comment: I want to avoid using events. I want to get the number even if the call is already ongoing before my app is launched.